# In Appcelerator Titanium, how can I get Django's CSRF token?

Tags: python, django, titanium, csrf, appcelerator

I'm using both Appcelerator Titanium and Python's Django to create a mobile app. As you might have guessed, Django is being used for the back-end. At the moment I'm trying to create a login form which requires a CSRF token to accept the data correctly. I'm trying to retrieve the CSRF token from Django, but I've tried and failed, and Google doesn't have any answers for me.

The problem is normally you'd get an HTML page with a CSRF token included in the form and just send it. What I'm trying to do now is send a POST without knowing the CSRF. In appcelerator, I've tried running

```
HTTPSession.open(GET, *url*)
token = HTTPSession.getRecievedHeaders("X-CSRF-TOKEN")
HTTPSession.open(POST, *url)
HTTPSession.getRecievedHeaders("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token)
HTTPSession.send(data)
```

But this doesn't work because of how Titanium works. So how can I get the token? Do I need to create a specific url just to create a session and display a CSRF token? I'm just worried that once I've recieved the token, I'll need to reconnect to the server and the token will have changed.

During my Googling, I found that Drupal has a function for this at the url: `services/session/token`

Is there an equivillant for this in Django? Or do I need to create my own page showing just a CSRF token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create my own function in Django to achieve this, but I finally got it working!

```
function getCSRF() {
    var csrfHTTP = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function() {
            Ti.App.Properties.setString("csrf", this.responseText);
        }
    });
    csrfHTTP.open("GET", "http://website.com/api/csrftoken/");
    csrfHTTP.send();
}
```

Then retrieve it via

```
Ti.App.Properties.getString("csrf")
```

and use it:

```
loginHTTP.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Ti.App.Properties.getString("csrf"));
```

Connecting to the website once creates a session in Django also creating a csrf token for that specific IP to use so you can retrieve it multiple times if needed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Titanium for app creation you can use [SetRequestHeader](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-method-setRequestHeader) for setting the token with the request.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, like loginHTTP.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Ti.App.Properties.getString("csrf"));, but that didn't explain how to retrieve the CSRF token. Thanks anyway!